# How can I replace youtube short code to iframe?

Tags: javascript

There is youtube short code from using wordpress

```
[youtube id="YOUTUBE_ID" width="650"]
```

And I have to replace short code to iframe

```
<iframe
  class="ql-video ql-align-center"
  frameborder="0"
  allowfullscreen="true"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YOUTUBE_ID?showinfo=0"
>
```

The iframe is not HTML element tag. This is just string from server database. I'm using with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

The whole string value is like

```
<p class="ql-align-center"><br></p><p class="ql-align-center">test</p>
<p class="ql-align-center"><br></p>
<iframe class="ql-video ql-align-center" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YOUTUBE_ID?showinfo=0"></iframe>
<p class="ql-align-center"><br></p>
```

```js
const originContent = '<div>test</div><h1>test</h1>[youtube id="YOUTUBE_ID" width=650] <p>test</p>'

const youtubeShortCode = '[youtube id="YOUTUBE_ID" width=650]'
const youtubeId = "YOUTUBE_ID"

const content = originContent.replace(youtubeShortCode, `<iframe class="ql-video ql-align-center" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${youtubeId}?showinfo=0"></iframe>`)

console.log(content)
```

Actually I don't know how can I get `youtubeShortCode` and `youtubeId`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search the YouTube ID and replace html in just one line code by using [String​.prototype​.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
const originContent = '<div>test</div><h1>test</h1>[youtube id="YOUTUBE_ID" width=650] <p>test</p>'

const content = originContent.replace(/\[youtube id=\"([^"]+)\" width=(\d+)\]/i, '<iframe class="ql-video ql-align-center" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1?showinfo=0"></iframe>')

console.log(content)
```

Or, if you just want to get the ID and width, you can match it by using [String​.prototype​.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```
const originContent = '<div>test</div><h1>test</h1>[youtube id="YOUTUBE_ID" width=650] <p>test</p>'

const [, youtubeId, width] = originContent.match(/\[youtube id=\"([^"]+)\" width=(\d+)\]/i)

console.log(youtubeId, width)
```